# Android Firebase - Why Null Values in Map fields are ignored

Tags: java, android, firebase

I discovered when saving a POJO with a map field using Firebase on Android, that if that map contains nulls in the value property of that map, then the whole field is ignored.

The workaround is easy (non-null values will result in the map saving successfully), but I want to understand why is this so?

**Model**

```
public class Game {

    private String owner;
    private Map<String, String> characters;

    public Game() {
        // empty constructor for Firebase
    }

    public String getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(String owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getCharacters() {
        return characters;
    }

    public void setCharacters(Map<String, String> characters) {
        this.characters = characters;
    }
}
```

**Calling code**

```
final Game game = new Game();
        game.setOwner("owner");
        game.setCharacters(new HashMap<String, String>());
        game.getCharacters().put("Bugs Bunny", null);
        game.getCharacters().put("Batman", null);
        final Firebase ref = new Firebase("<firebaseurl>/test/" + System.currentTimeMillis());
        ref.setValue(game);
```

**Resulting object in Firebase**

```
{
    "1456421340781": {
        "owner": "owner"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're actually not ignored. When you give Firebase a `null` value for a property/path, you indicate that you want to property or path to be deleted.

From the [documentation on Firebase's JavaScript `set()` method](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/set.html):

> Passing null for the new value is equivalent to calling `remove()`; all data at this location or any child location will be deleted.

So if you set a value with:

```
ref.child("keith").setValue(47649);
```

Then the following will delete it:

```
ref.child("keith").setValue(null);
```

This behavior is most useful when you use `updateChildren()`, but it works equally when you call `setValue()`.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I didn't RTFM well enough, have since found "Note that passing null to setValue() will remove the data at the specified location." and "Note that passing null in a map will delete the data at that location in the database." on https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html

Comment: Great. I was indeed looking for that last one for my answer, but failed t. find it. I'll remove the bit about it not being documented for Android, from my answer then.